# Gitversion. How to force decrement

Tags: decrement, gitversion

I'm new to GitVersion and not fully understand how it works.
GitVersion for develop branch shows 4.2.0.
Develop is merged to master.
GitVersion for master shows 4.1.2

What i need is 4.1.3 on develop. Decrement 4.2.0 -> 4.1.3.
I'm using GitVersion on Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

The [default configuration](https://gitversion.net/docs/configuration#branch-configuration) for the `develop` branch is `increment: Minor`. If you add a `GitVersion.yml` file in your repository (and I think you need to tell AzDO about its location; a peculiarity with the AzDO task, not inherent in GitVersion) and configure `develop` to `increment: Patch`  I think you'll get the behaviour you want. Example:

```
branches:
  develop:
    increment: Patch
```